# How to solve cross origin and get response data using angular http get method call?

Tags: angular, proxy, cross-browser, odata

I am facing a problem in getting sap odata in angular application.
I have consuming the sap odata link in my angular service call using get method trying to access and get the data. I have configured proxy.conf.json for proxy to connect the sap link but i am facing a problem that i am unable to get the response from the server side.
Please find the proxy.config.json file content

```
{
    "/sap": {
        "target" : "http://server.domain.com:8002",
        "secure" : false,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/sap": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }

}
```

Below is my angular service call

```
constructor(private host: string, private http: Http) {
    }
    var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json ');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','application/json');
            headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');

            return this.http.get('http://server.domain.com:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ABC_FD_SRV/ID_GEN_Set?sap-client=010', {headers}).pipe(map((response: any) => response));
```

I can see the networks that status is OK and code is 200, but in response tab no response only blank received. But in service console i received only like this

```
Response {_body: "", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://server.domain.com:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ABC_FD_SRV/ID_GEN_Set?sap-client=010"
_body: ""
__proto__: Body
```

But when i paste the url in the browser i can see the data in xml format or url change to json format.

Can anyone check my code if anything i have missed out to config the proxy.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your problem properly, but all headers you setup for angular xhr request should be set on the server side in response, not in request from angular application. Especially `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is important  in case of cors

Comment: I do not have server side cors configuration, instead of server side functionality how to achieve by proxy. Since i have tried it, i am able to hit the link and status code is 200. But  i don't receive any response its empty